# Listbox Scrolling like windows phone

Tags: wpf, listbox, scroll, listboxitem, smooth-scrolling

Im trying to use (in a WPF application) the listbox as I used into Windows Phone 7.1 Application.

In my Wp7 app the scroll is smooth and I can hold one listboxitem and scroll it!

Is that possible to be done with WPF? If yes, how? Examples?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [SurfaceListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.surface.presentation.controls.surfacelistbox.aspx) class. It is part of the [Microsoft Surface 2.0 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff727815) which runs on Windows 7.